# Androidstudio gapps has stopped in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services, emulation

I'm a newbie in Android Studio. I created a 'Hello World' project then ran it in an emulator. But the Emulator always gave me an error-

[image: Unfortunately, com.google.process.gapps has stopped.]

My installed SDKs are-

[image]

I cannot do anything on the emulator. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have platform tools to develop anything for android. Also if you're testing on an emulator you need to have the system images for that particular API against which you are developing, ie, your target API. You haven't yet installed all the packages you should to start developing. You can visit https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html for more information about the required packages.

To download packages, open Android Studio, go to Configure and the SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I updated SDK tool and SDK Platform-tools then problem was fixed.

Comment: @YasinYörük If this solved your problem you should accept this as an answer so that other people facing the same problem get the correct answer at once. Just click the grey tick mark beneath the answer score to accept it. Once you do so it will turn green.

Comment: I know how to use stackoverflow. But I think this is not a complete solution. You just give me an advice. Then it's worked.

Comment: I have answered it perfectly and also added some advice. It wasn't working because you need to have system images for the emulator to do **anything**. I quote from my answer, '_Also if you're testing on an emulator you need to have the system images for that particular API against which you are developing, ie, your target API._'